# How to get Up Navigation behavior exactly like back button pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation, onbackpressed, up-navigation

How can I get the Up Navigation button to behave like the back button? When I press the back button all my previous activities remain as the were prior.
When I press the up button my activities return to initial state. I tried hooking up onBackPressed(); to case R.id.home on my onOptionsItemSelected but it still behaves differently.

Visual: 
Back Button Behavior-
https://www.flickr.com/photos/151974643@N07/35702817566/in/dateposted-public/ Up Button Behavior - https://www.flickr.com/photos/151974643@N07/35702812926/in/dateposted-public/
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it several ways, put this code in **onCreate()** method of your activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        YOUR_ACTIVITY.this.onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked! thank you so much, I appreciate the help.